# Dynamically added input field disappearing rightaway

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a jQuery snippet, in which I can add input fields dynamically on click of 'Add Image' button (code below) using jQuery appendTo() function. However, everytime I click on the button the textbox appears and then disappears rightaway. I have noticed that others have also faced this problem, but am not able to find a proper solution for this problem. Can someone please help me out with this?

```
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4" id="images-div">
        <input type="text" name="txt-image[]" class="span4 txt-input-field">
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        <button class="btn" id="btn-add-image">Add Image</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn-add-image').click(function() {
            $('<input type="text" name="txt-image[]" class="span4 txt-input-field">').appendTo('#images-div');
        });
    });
</script>
...
```

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/DNXB4/ There must be some other part of the code that's interfering.

Comment: Why *Add Image* **adds textbox** ?! =)

Comment: @Juhana Does that mean that this problem might have to do with the DOM structure?

Comment: @gdoron I am hoping to create a control that the user can use to either upload a file or link to an existing URL. Do you have any suggestions for good opensource plugins that can do similar thing?

Comment: @DEREKN It means there's some other JavaScript code that you're not showing that's hiding the new input. Do you have a "remove image" button or anything else that would remove input fields?

Comment: Thanks @Juhana. I have solved the problem by calling event.preventDefault() function. Problem updated with solution.

Comment: @DEREKN Please put your answer as an answer, so you can accept it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer provided by DEREK N](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9656595/2):

---

Problem solved by using preventDefault() function, as shown below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn-add-image').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('<input type="text" name="txt-image[]" class="span4 txt-input-field">').appendTo('#images-div');
        });
    });
</script>
```